# Is there a Python-ealy way to run Scala scripts with dependencies?

Tags: scala, maven, build, sbt

The ways I know about so far are

- Create an ant `build.xml` file, make compile and run tasks, and include appropriate jars in a `classpath=`
- Make at `sbt` project and include dependencies with version numbers in `build.sbt`
- Make a maven project and include dependencies in the xml file
- Run from the command line setting `-classpath` explicitly

None of these are bad, but it feels like extra work after being babied with

```
import json

json.loads('[1, 2]')
```

and having that work right off the bat, provided I have `json` installed. In particular tracking down appropriate versions on Mavenhub gets a little tiresome.

Though maybe I'm just being too picky ;-)

Comment: You aren't too picky, you're just plain wrong. You are comparing external dependencies in Scala to importing stuff from the standard library in Python.

Comment: How does Python deal with different versions of libraries?

Comment: @Kim Stebel they don't have to be standard library packages; they just have to be... "installed".

Comment: @ziggystar it doesn't (or I don't know how to if it does), which is a problem sometimes, but for just little stuff I'm playing with isn't an issue.

Comment: @Owen: That doesn't make this comparison any fairer. I Java/Scala I could just put a bunch of jars into a standard location thus "installing" them.

Comment: @Kim Stebel Sorry if it sounded like I was comparing. I realize they're serving different purposes; I was just trying to communicate what I was after, and Python was the best analogy.

Comment: Or Groovy's @Grab annotation: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is xsbtscript: https://github.com/paulp/xsbtscript

It allows you to create a single script file which includes both the sbt config your code requires along with the Scala code itself.

Comment: this is gone, anyone know where it went?

Comment: Paul Philips is @extempore2 on Twitter, so I guess that might be the way to hit him up about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think [scalas](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Scripts) from [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup) is better. Either install [conscript](https://github.com/n8han/conscript) and run this command:

```
cs harrah/xsbt --branch v0.10.1
```

Or create it by hand:

```
java -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain -Dsbt.boot.directory=/home/user/.sbt/boot -jar sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

And then use it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
!#

/***
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-twitter" % "0.8.3",
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.3"
)
*/

import dispatch.{ json, Http, Request }
import dispatch.twitter.Search
import json.{ Js, JsObject }

def process(param: JsObject) = {
  val Search.text(txt)        = param
  val Search.from_user(usr)   = param
  val Search.created_at(time) = param

  "(" + time + ")" + usr + ": " + txt
}

Http.x((Search("#scala") lang "en") ~> (_ map process foreach println))
```

Paul's [xsbtscript](https://github.com/paulp/xsbtscript) is basically a shell that downloads and install all necessary components to do the same thing. It usually works well, but has some limitations (won't go through authenticated proxies, for instance).